# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined after modifying form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js, use-state

I am currently working on an application with node.js, express and ReactJs. I am also using sequelize as my ORM. I was working on my form which originally sent nulls to my database and since then I have been stuck on this error for a few days. I am getting the following on my frontend ReactJs:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined'**

I know this error is very vague and happens for many reasons. For me it happened when I was working on my form.I am using `useStates` to set my values and using axios to handle the post request.
Where I declared my states:

```js
  let [state, setState] = useState({
    leadName: "",
    excellentLead: ""
  });
```

`handleChange(evt)` function:Used to handle changes based on my input.

```js
  function handleChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/add",
      data: body,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    setState({
      ...state,
      [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
    });
```

Current form(I am using **React Bootstrap** for styling.):

```js
            <Form onSubmit={handleChange}>
              <Form.Group controlId="formBasicName">
                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Name"
                  name="leadName"
                  value={state.leadName}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group controlId="formBasicFollowUp">
                <Form.Label>
                  Excellent Lead Worth following up(Yes/No/Maybe)
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Name"
                  name="excellentLead"
                  value={state.excellentLead}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Form.Group>
               <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
```

In my `server.js` this is my post route:

```js
app.post('/add', function(request, response) {
  Information.create({
    Name:req.body.leadName,
    ExcellentLeadWorthFollowingUp:req.body.excellentLead
  }).then(function(Information){
    res.json(Information);
  })
})
```

I don't have any issues connecting to the database from the front end and my post method used to send nulls on a button click which wasn't the goal. To add, this error broke my entire program.

Any suggestions, explanations or links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import { response } from 'express';
Was imported and that caused the error this whole time....A classic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed your error, I would like to make you aware that you are calling `handleChange` every time your input changes. This means you are making a `POST` request every time you type a character in your input.

A better approach would be to only do your post on submit.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "", age: "" });

  const handleChange = (e, field) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action

    // set your data state
    setData({
      ...data,
      [field]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // axios post data

    console.log(data); // just for showing
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Fill in data</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={data.name}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "name")}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={data.age}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "age")}
        />
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you I did try that and now it is not sending 20-30 rows of null data eat time I submit!

Comment: That shouldn't happen, is your submit handler different from your onchange handler?

Comment: I changed the code, setting the initial value to null is possible for when a `GET` request is done in `useEffect`, excuse me for that. I changed the initial values, this should work now.

Comment: You could try out this sandbox if you like https://codesandbox.io/s/sp01-submitting-inputs-gdtbu let me know if you encounter more problems.

Comment: It worked out for me at the end.The problem was from the backend. Thank you so much for your help!Now it all works!